# Remove selected routes from production build in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, build

Is there a way to remove some routes with their linked components from production build of Vue app?

In my app I have manager interface that only I use so there is no need to have it's logic in the production build. I want to avoid having any of manager's code actually used in the production build as I can use the manager page only during development on localhost.

Here is simple example what I have now. The managerCheck tests if user is manager to allow user to enter or to redirect him back to the homepage. This is probably enough as it is also combined with check in MongoDB but I still would love to not includes manager's components logic inside production build as ManagerView includes pretty powerful functions and it is better to be safe than sorry.

```js
// router.js
// ... some imports

const userCheck = (to, from, next) => store.getters['user/user'] ?  next() : next({path: '/login'})
const managerCheck = (to, from, next) => store.getters['user/manager'] ?  next() : next({path: '/'})

export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'App Name',
      component: MainView,
    },
    {
      path: '/user',
      name: 'User',
      component: UserView,
      beforeEnter: userCheck
    },
    {
      path: '/manager',
      name: 'Manager',
      component: ManagerView,
      beforeEnter: managerCheck
    }
})
```

Comment: It largely depends on how you're using Vue, but chances are `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? devRoutes: prodRoutes` should work. Obviously, `devRoutes` should be a merge of `prodRoutes` with whatever you don't want in prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
// router.js
// ... some imports

const userCheck = (to, from, next) => store.getters['user/user'] ?  next() : next({path: '/login'})
const managerCheck = (to, from, next) => store.getters['user/manager'] ?  next() : next({path: '/'})

const clientRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'App Name',
    component: MainView,
  },
  {
    path: '/user',
    name: 'User',
    component: UserView,
    beforeEnter: userCheck
  }
]

const managerRoutes = []

// you may have to look into process.env to set this condition correctly
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  managerRoutes.push({
    path: '/manager',
    name: 'Manager',
    component: ManagerView,
    beforeEnter: managerCheck
  })
}


export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [...clientRoutes, ...managerRoutes]
})
```

**process.env**: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't thought of that, it is great simple solution.

Answer (score 7):

In production, unnecessary routes can be filtered out.

Routes can be defined with productionAvailable flag.

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'App Name',
      component: MainView,
      productionAvailable: true,
    },
    {
      path: '/user',
      name: 'User',
      component: UserView,
      beforeEnter: userCheck,
      productionAvailable: true,
    },
    {
      path: '/manager',
      name: 'Manager',
      component: ManagerView,
      beforeEnter: managerCheck,
      productionAvailable: false,
    }
}]
```

Then filter it when exporting if the node env is set to `production`.

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? routes.filter((route) => route.productionAvailable) : routes,
})
```

Comment: Also great and simple solution, thanks for your time.